# How to deserialize in Jackson JSON created using @JsonIdentityInfo

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson, lombok

Given the following JSON:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "code": "HR",
  "employees": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "department": 1,
      "serial": {
        "id": 254,
        "type": {
          "code": "XYZ",
          "active": true
        }
      }
    }]
}
```

How would I have Jackson deserialize this into the below classes? I've tried this:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonIdentityInfo(scope=Department.class, generator = ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property = "id")
public class Department {
   int id;
   String code;
   List<Employee> employees
}


@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonIdentityInfo(scope=Employee.class, generator = ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property = "id")
public class Employee {
   int id;
   Department department;  
   Serial serial;

}
```

But I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: No Object Id found for an instance of `com.example.domain.Employee`, to assign to property 'id'; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: No Object Id found for an instance of `com.example.domain.Employee`, to assign to property 'id'
     at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 713] (through reference chain: com.example.domain.Department["employees"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])
```

Note: `code` is a key for `Department`. `Department` id and `Serial` id form the key for `Employee`.

Comment: In your employee class ignore `@JsonIgnore Department department;`

Comment: just change `department` type  to integer in `Employee ` class

Comment: @deadshot & @MichalRosa - thanks for your response. I cannot change `department` type to integer in `Employee` class. `Department` is only represented as an integer when it has already been referenced previously in the JSON. See [this](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/misc/jackson/json-identity-info-annotation.html) for more information. So, your suggestion may work for the example response that I provided but will not work in the general case.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, you're missing the semicolon in  `List<Employee> employees` :))

also, my believe is that these classes are in a standalone .java files, since they are both public. but without that you shouldn't even be able to compile your code :)) so I assume you got these two things covered.

I also believe that there might be a problem with the department in the Employee class - in your class, it's a Department type, but in your JSON, it's an int type.

try to switch the type in your Employee class of the property department from Department into int - I would also suggest to rename it into "departmentId" or something like that.